# Why "la clase turista" and "primera clase" in Spanish?

Tags: adjetivos

I have encountered the following two sentences in Rosetta Stone Spanish course:

> Los pasajeros de la clase turista comen.
>
> Los pasajeros de primera clase comen.

It seems that if you mention *economy class*, you express it as `la clase turista`, but on first class, you express it as `primera clase`.

1. Why does the latter case not use an article?
2. Why does the latter case use an adjective before the *class*?

How can I distinguish the other cases such as *business class* or *premium economy*?

*NOTE: Please answer the question in English.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjectives that describe number, such as "primera", always come before the noun.

Business class is referred to as "clase ejecutiva."

Secondly, it is common to say "pasajeros de clase turista" without the article. I don't know why the lesson placed it on one and not the other.

Usually we omit the article in Spanish after the preposition "de", especially when the preposition is creating a description of a noun. In the sentences you provided, the phrases "clase turista" and "primera clase" describe the passengers. The first sentence, in my opinion, would be better without the article.